# How to take some specific word from string in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql that contain two columns or fields, one column is for an `id_column` and others for `description` of string type. I would like to insert an specific string to the column `description`.

For example:

```
insert into table_name (id, description) values ('1','we go to school')
```

And then in my php file, I would like to fetch the specific word **"school"**  from the column `description`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to take the third word? The one that's literally "school"? The requirements aren't clear here.

Comment: Do you want to take the 4th word in all the descriptions?

Comment: i want take spesific word that i determined before. in this case, i determine that i will take word "school". so word school will taken finally...

Comment: How will you determine the word? do you know that the words will exists?

Comment: may be `LIKE Clause` will help you : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm

Comment: What is your word choosing pattern?

Comment: actually in that column i have contain html tag, and i need to take tag "img" from that column.

Comment: So You need to select the column with the a specific word(like school), and then find the src attribute of img tag??

Answer (score 1):

You can use like with wildchar .

```
   select * from your_table 
   where description like '%school%';
```

in php for find if a string contain a word you can use

```
$my_string = 'we go to school';

if (strpos($my_strong, 'school') !== false) {
   echo 'string found';
}
```

Comment: and how to i take just word "school" in php? i need word shool, not data column that contain word "school".

Answer (score 0):

You'll be needing to use **[SQL Wildcard Characters](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)**

So your query can be something like:

```
select * from tabel where description like '%school%';
```

EDIT :

I guess you need to get description first then according to it you want to manage the output.

For that try this :

```
$sqldata= mysqli_query('select * from tabel)';
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sqldata);
if($rowcount > 0)
{
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqldata)) // fetch records
    {
       $description = $result['desription'];
       $id = $result['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to i take just word "school" in php? i need word shool, not data column that contain word "school".

Comment: @RuslanWahyudi, you mean to say you need to match that word or check the string ? OR the `school` is dynamic in place of that `we` can also come

Comment: Please check my updated answer @RuslanWahyudi, but still your point is not clear at all what needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understand what you want. But I guess, you want to get image source from the description column.

```
$q = mysql_query("select id, description from tabel");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

$html = $row["description"];

preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@', $html, $match );

$src = array_pop($match);

echo $src;
```